# How to import in Unity, and use , "external" animation like the ones you can download on Mixamo?

Tags: unity, animation

I've a 3d Character with some animations. Then, i've found some animations on Mixamo i would like to use with my 3d model.

Do I need to merge them ?

If not, what's the correct way to download them and use in my project ?

Thanks